# Highcharts with Icon Markers Plugin isn't rendering FontAwesome points

Tags: javascript, highcharts, font-awesome

One of Highcharts' examples is [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2A7Zf/) which gives a plugin that allows FontAwesome icons to be rendered as points on a chart.

I'm trying to incorporate the same thing on a project I'm working on, however when I add a point to the chart (by either manually altering the `data` object within the individual `series` or by calling the series' `addPoint` method) the point doesn't show up. The axis however does get updated.

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yc3Tg/).

In this JSFiddle example I've included the plugin right at the top, given the chart some basic default options to populate the axes, and then attempted to add some points. Here is the relevant code from this example:

```
// Generate the event series if undefined
if (typeof eventChartOptions.options.series == 'undefined')
    eventChartOptions.options.series = [];

// Populate the event series based on data in events object
eventChartOptions.options.series.push(
    {
        data: [[174.0, 65.6]],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'text:\uf183' // fa-male
        },
        icon: '\uf183',
        name: 'Male',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, 0.6)'
    }
);

eventChart = new Highcharts.Chart(eventChartOptions.options);
```

On the rendered chart, the yAxis gets updated to include the new value (of 174), but the icon is nowhere to be seen:

[image: Chart example]

Doing a bit of comparison between Highcharts' own example and my code reveals that my series is missing a Graphic object:

#### Highcharts Series Point Array (working)

```
points: Array[35]
    0: Ea
        category: 161.2
        clientX: 222.50362775079438
        graphic: G
            added: true
            element: text
            parentGroup: G
            parentInverted: undefined
            renderer: ta
            stroke: "#FFFFFF"
            stroke-width: 0
            styles: Object
            textStr: ""
            textWidth: undefined
            xSetter: function (a,b,c){var d=c.getElementsByTagName("tspan"),
            __proto__: Object
        negative: false
        options: Object
            x: 161.2
            y: 51.6
            __proto__: Object
        plotX: 222.50362775079438
        plotY: 179.77142857142854
        pointAttr: Array[0]
        series: c
        x: 161.2
        y: 51.6
        yBottom: null
        __proto__: Object
```

#### My Series Point Array (not working)

```
points: Array[1]
    0: Ea
        category: 174
        clientX: 112.5
        negative: false
        options: Object
            x: 174
            y: 65.6
            __proto__: Object
        plotX: 112.5
        plotY: 275339.2173783309
        pointAttr: Array[0]
        series: c
        x: 174
        y: 65.6
        yBottom: null
        __proto__: Object
        length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your data is incorrect for the x-axis where you are trying to put your icon.

You have been using

```
// Populate the event series based on data in events object
    eventChartOptions.options.series.push(
        {
            data: [[174.0, 65.6]] ,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'text:\uf183' // fa-male
            },
            icon: '\uf183',
            name: 'Male',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, 0.6)'
        }
    );
```

Which indicates a value of `65.4` which is nowhere near the ranges defined for the other axis such as `1390219200000`

Changing to

```
// Populate the event series based on data in events object
eventChartOptions.options.series.push({
    data: [
        [174.0, 1390219200000]
    ],
    marker: {
        symbol: 'text:\uf183' // fa-male
    },
    icon: '\uf183',
    name: 'Male',
    color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, 0.6)'
});
```

Does render the man albeit at 90 degrees?!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/yc3Tg/1/

Comment: It's rendered that way because `chart.inverted` option is set to true.

Comment: Ah of course! I hadn't considered the axes values at all, thanks a lot!